# GET all data from WEB API using console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2, console-application, dotnet-httpclient

I have created a `web-API` of products following [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) tutorial. The 2nd tutorial is the console application in which the `web-api` is called. Now when I create a single product then it is view able. But when I create more than one products than only the last entry is view able. For better understanding see the below code.

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    static void ShowProduct(Product product)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"Name: {product.Name}\tPrice: {product.Price}\tCategory: {product.Category}");
    }

    static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/product/", product);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        // return URI of the created resource.
        return response.Headers.Location;
    }

    static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)
    {
        Product product = null;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
        }
        return product;
    }
static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        int a;
        decimal price = 0;
        string name = null, category = null;
        char option;
        //string url;
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:7361/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        Uri url = null;

        try
        {
            label:
            Console.Write("1. Create a product\n");
            Console.Write("2. View products\n");
            Console.Write("3. Update a product\n");
            Console.Write("4. Delete a product\n");
            Console.Write("5. Exit\n");

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your choice: ");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            switch(a)
            {
                case 1:

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter name of the product: ");
                    name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter price of the product: ");
                    price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter category of the product: ");
                    category = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                    // Create a new product
                    Product product = new Product { Name = name, Price = price, Category = category };

                    url = await CreateProductAsync(product);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Created at {url}");

                    Console.WriteLine("Want to create more product(s)? (y/n): ");
                    option = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

                    if(option == 'y' || option == 'Y')
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        goto case 1;
                    }
                    else if(option == 'n' || option == 'N')
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        goto label;
                    }

                    break;

                case 2:

                    // Get the product
                    product = await GetProductAsync(url.PathAndQuery);

                    ShowProduct(product);

                    break;
                   //case 3:...
                  //case 4:...
                  //case 5:...
       }
```

I want to view all the created products. For this i have to create a list of products while creating them. But the problem is that I don't know where to do it?

**Update 1**

On debugging the code the `static async Task<Product> GetProductAsync(string path)` the `path` gets the last product id as 'api/product/2', but I want to be like that 'api/product/'. The path includes the last entered `id`.

**Update 2**

For getting all the products I have entered the `url` in `product = await GetProductAsync("http://localhost:7361/api/product");`

But now after running the application i am getting the below error.

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”})
```

**Update 3**

By checking the API response in `Postman` following is the data which i got

```
[
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "yo-yo",
    "Category": "toys",
    "Price": 45
},
{
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "mobile",
    "Category": "electronics",
    "Price": 45000
}]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: What JSON response you are getting from the API? `GetProductAsync` returns only one Product. `ShowProduct` method has only one instance of Product as argument and you are passing only one product to the `ShowProduct` argument. So surely it will display only one product. You need to check what is being returned by the API when you are requesting all the products from it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have done it in `Update 2`.

Comment: You need to know what JSON you are getting from API to understand why you are getting `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object` error. Looks like the API returns you the collection of products and you are trying to deserialize it to a single product. If you share the JSON response of the API, I can provide some concrete solution.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya kindly see the update 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON returned from the API (which returns all the products) represents the collection of objects but in your code you are trying to deserialize it to single product object.

```
product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
```

Following is the change you need to do to make your code working.
Create a new method which will call GetAllProducts API and return collection of products as following.

```
static async Task<List<Product>> GetAllProductsAsync(string path)
{
    List<Product> products = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Product>>();
    }
    return products;
}
```

I am suggesting to create new method because you might be using the old method somewhere else.
Now, use the new method as following in switch case 2:

```
case 2:
    // Get all the products
    var products = await GetAllProductsAsync(url.PathAndQuery);

    // Loop thru the products and call ShowProduct method for each product in the list.
    foreach(var product in products)
    {
         ShowProduct(product);
    }
```

This should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: I have added the code which you have provide but still it gives me the same error `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ClientSample.Product]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.`

Comment: Are you calling method `GetAllProductsAsync` in case 2: ?

Comment: On debugging the code the path is again `api/product/2`. And yes I am calling `GetALLProductAsync` in case 2. Also the `List<Product> products = new List<Product>();` the count is zero

Comment: Why path is `api/product/2`? because you are setting value of `url` in `case 1`. You need to use proper url value in `case 2`. Before calling `GetAllProductsAsync` set the value of `url` to proper API url. Simplest would be to call `GetAllProductsAsync` with value `api/product`.